# Remove .gz Extension

Tags: makefile, gzip

I have a Jekyll site that processes all HTML, CSS and Javascript into `*.css.gz`, `*.js.gz`, etc files.

The problem is, I need to remove the `gz` extension so the files can be uploaded to S3 and served using GZip.

In my makefile, I have this:

```
find _site/ -iname '*.html' -exec gzip -n {} +
find _site/ -iname '*.js' -exec gzip -n {} +
find _site/ -iname '*.css' -exec gzip -n {} +
find _site -iname '*.gz' -exec rename 's/\.gz$//i' {} +
```

The last line fails with:

```
find: rename: No such file or directory
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

When I run the command `find _site -iname '*.gz'`, I see all of the GZipped files correctly output and as far as I can tell they all exist.

How can I remove the extension, or modify the commands above to prevent the error?

*Source of script in my Makefile: http://fusion.dominicwatson.co.uk/2011/09/adding-gzip-to-my-jeyll-setup.html*

Comment: The command for renaming on Linux is 'mv'. No such thing as 'rename'.

Comment: Ah, that's the problem. I'm on Mac OS X, but how would I go about using `mv` to achieve the same effect?

Comment: You will need, probably, a shell script that calculates the new name from the old name and runs mv OLD NEW. Then execute that from find.

Answer (score 3):

Make a backup and then try this:

```
for f in `find _site -iname '*.gz'`; do
  mv $f ${f%.gz} 
done
```

That should loop over all of your files (from your find command), and rename them one-by-one using `mv`.  The `${f%.gz}` strips the .gz suffix from the filename.

Answer (score 0):

`find` can't execute `rename`, most likely because it's not installed on your system.

You need an implementation of it (eg. [`prename`](https://gist.github.com/883553) or `apt-get install perl` if you are using a Debian derivative) for that to work.

Comment: Please expand on your answer.